# Scraping to remove logo from a HTML file works for text but not for images

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I've been trying to remove an image from a HTML page using scraping. The code works fine for textual data, but not images.

Here is the HTML file I'm trying to modify -->

[image: Original Image]

My output -->

[image]

My code -->

```
def lux_overall(eda_file, vis_file_path):
    
    # Overall LUX
    eda_file.save_as_html(vis_file_path)
    
    
    links=['<div id="footer-description">\
             <a href="https://github.com/lux-org/lux/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lux-org/lux-resources/master/logo/logo.png" width="65px" style="vertical-align: middle;"></a>\
            </div>']

    find_word = 'These visualizations were generated by'
    replace_with = ""
    
 

    with open(vis_file_path, 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                content = f.read()
               
                content = content.replace(find_word, replace_with)
                content = content.replace(links[0], replace_with)
                
                          
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                f.write(content)
                               
    
    return vis_file_path
```

Where's the issue? Why isn't image being erased here?

There's nothing wrong with the link being supplied. I used the 'Hide Element' option to verify the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use BeautifulSoup for this.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

html = """
<span>Should be kept</span>
<div class="footer">
    <p>Image generated by:</p>
    <img src="https://http.cat/418" />
</div>
<div class="nonsense">
    <p>Should be kept as well</p>
    <img src="https://example.com/nonsense.png" />
</div>
"""

soup = bs4(html, "lxml")
footer = soup.findAll(class_="footer")[0]
footer.decompose()
print(soup.contents)
```

Select the footer by its class or ID or tagname or whatever. See the bs4 docs for more explanations. Beware, findAll() will return a list, so yo need to select the correct item in the list. `footer.decompose()` will remove the footer element and it's children recursively.

This, after decomposing, the following will be left:

```html
<html><body><span>Should be kept</span>

<div class="nonsense">
<p>Should be kept as well</p>
<img src="https://example.com/nonsense.png"/>
</div>
</body></html>
```